# HTML tamanho da imagem em uma tabela

Tags: html

Como faco pra deixar uma imagem menor usando so HTML nesse codigo? ja usei Width depois do link e nao funciona

```
<a href="window.open('file:///C:/Users/cliente/Desktop/Projeto%20Leticia/Cadastro.html')";>
  <img src= "C:\Users\cliente\Desktop\Projeto\PICON_028.png"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Em que imagem? poste o codigo!

Comment: <th><a href="window.open('file:///C:/Users/cliente/Desktop/Projeto%20Leticia/Cadastro.html')";><img src= "C:\Users\cliente\Desktop\Projeto\PICON_025.png">

Comment: Respondi sua pergunta.

Comment: Caramba vlw cara

Comment: Avisa se resolver seu problema, e não esquece de marcar como resolvido

Comment: Onde eu marco como resolvido, sou novo.

Comment: Lá na resposta tem um icone de check, é só clicar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução sugerida pelo Rafael esclarece sua dúvida, porém, ela define o mesmo tamanho para todas as imagens da página, o que não costuma ser um abordagem adequada. Para aplicar a formatação apenas nesta imagem é melhor:

CSS

```
.minha-imagem{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<img src= "C:\Users\cliente\Desktop\Projeto\PICON_028.png" class="minha-imagem"/>
```

Lembrando que se você inserir o css dentro de um @media query poderá definir diferentes tamanhos conforme a resolução de tela, o que seria aconselhável para adaptar o site a equipamentos móveis, tais como tablets e telefones. Daí, por exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .minha-imagem{
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim usando `CSS`

```css
img{
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Imagem</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="window.open('file:///C:/Users/cliente/Desktop/Projeto%20Leticia/Cadastro.html')";><img src= "https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/kit-harington-got.jpg"/></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```